# yahoo-finance python library not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yahoo-finance

today I'm try to use yahoo-finance library than some issue occur by code.
i provide code and occurred error. 
here is library link https://pypi.org/project/yahoo-finance/

code:-

```py
from yahoo_finance import Share
yahoo = Share('YHOO')
print(yahoo.get_open())
```

Error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1254, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1300, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1249, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1036, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 974, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1407, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 946, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 704, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    yahoo = Share('YHOO')
  File "/home/yogesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yahoo_finance/__init__.py", line 178, in __init__
    self.refresh()
  File "/home/yogesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yahoo_finance/__init__.py", line 142, in refresh
    self.data_set = self._fetch()
  File "/home/yogesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yahoo_finance/__init__.py", line 181, in _fetch
    data = super(Share, self)._fetch()
  File "/home/yogesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yahoo_finance/__init__.py", line 134, in _fetch
    data = self._request(query)
  File "/home/yogesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yahoo_finance/__init__.py", line 118, in _request
    response = yql.YQLQuery().execute(query)
  File "/home/yogesh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yahoo_finance/yql.py", line 61, in execute
    'env': DATATABLES_URL
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

i have a no idea about this error, please help me to solve this problem. Thank you....

Comment: The error indicated that python was unable to resolve the DNS address of the service where the API call was made. It could be an issue with your system or the service itself.

Comment: looks like this lib is dead, [this github issue](https://github.com/lukaszbanasiak/yahoo-finance/issues/148) points to the backend not being run anymore ... guess you need to look for an alternative :/

Comment: You can try [yahooquery](https://github.com/dpguthrie/yahooquery).  Seems to be actively maintained and provides similar functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The package is broken. See for example, this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/lukaszbanasiak/yahoo-finance/issues/148

Your best bet would be to indicate on GitHub that the package is not working and perhaps the author is able to help you further.